# Changing the subroutine template

Tags: abap

In ABAP in SAPGUI (SE38 or SE80), if I write

```
perform test_form using p_var.
```

and double click on *test_form*, it will suggest that it creates the following subroutine for me.

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Form  TEST_FORM
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*      -->P_P_VAR  text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
form TEST_FORM  using    p_p_var.

endform.                    " TEST_FORM
```

Is it possible for me to change this template?

Comment: As far as I remember it is possible. I have to refresh my memory on how to do it and I will get back to you.

Comment: Do You want to change the created stub or Do You want to change the template, in order to create other stubs as default ?

Comment: The latter - Every time I use this method of creating a subroutine, I do many of the same changes. I want the auto generated code to always already have these changes.

Comment: I was wrong. A little debugging showed that the comment construction is hardcoded in the subroutine `COMBLOCK` of function group `SPPR`. You can look at it by yourself by debugging function module `PRETTY_PRINTER`.

Comment: Maybe creating your own pattern will help? [Here](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=60653655) are some hints. However the double click feature will not be available with such a solution...

Comment: Thanks Jagger, that's a good idea. I can probably use patterns for some other things, if not this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The templates are defined in the table `TSE05` with the key `APP_OBJ`= `ADDM` and - for FORM routines - the keyword `PU`.

[image: TSE05]

Place a break-point in the function module `DETERMINE_BLOCK` to observe the process in detail. Whether you want to modify the standard entries is up to you...

Comment: +1 Good answer, however it does not seem to be working for pretty printer, which after all is not what is being asked in the question. For Pretty Printer the comment seems to be hardcoded.

Comment: I tried changing this table and also looked in the debugger for DETERMINE_BLOCK. I made some changes to the form routine template, but some of the stuff is hard coded. Thanks for the helpful answer. :)